# WooCommerce 5.4.1 - Formatting price visually $product->get_price()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I need visually remove the decimal place (00) from the price and maintain only the comma or point after the first integer.

**E.g: $ 10,**

**E.g: $ 7,**

This is the code:

```
$retorno .= "<div class='cc_btn_checkout_container d-none' data-price='".$product->get_price()."'><div
```

The object receives the price: .$product->get_price(). = **$ 10.00**

The price is displayed here inside:

```
 <p id='cc_btn_amount'>$ 10.00</p>
```

I'm trying with this function....but until now nothing happens.

```
$retorno .= "<div class='cc_btn_checkout_container d-none' data-price='".number_format($product->get_price(), 0)."'><div
```

The number need to be displayed like this: **$ 10,**

How can I do this? Is that the correct function to be used in this case?

Obs: I must maintain the comma after the price, I cannot in this case remove the comma or the point as others Woo functions does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the functions in this article from [Tyche Softwares](https://www.tychesoftwares.com/how-to-stylise-the-decimal-values-in-prices-in-woocommerce/)

Just remove $decimal from the return and the `<sup>` if you don't need it.

"If you want the decimal separator in the superscript, you can easily do that too. If you look at our filter, it has an argument called $decimal_separator. This is the same separator which we have set in the WooCommerce settings. We just have to include that in our final result. Here is an example –

```
add_filter( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', 'ts_woo_decimal_price', 10, 5 );
function ts_woo_decimal_price( $formatted_price, $price, $decimal_places, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator ) {
    $unit = number_format( intval( $price ), 0, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator );
    $decimal = sprintf( '%02d', ( $price - intval( $price ) ) * 100 );
    return $unit . '<sup>' . $decimal_separator. $decimal . '</sup>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this filter
http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_price_format/
or this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', '__return_true' );
```